# How am i using getchar() wrong?

Tags: c, getchar

OK so basically I'm trying to get a program that transforms a hexadecimal that i enter into its equivalent base 10 value, i'm pretty sure the algorithm is correct, i just cant get it to correctly read what i enter, any help is much appreciated :) And I'm sorry to anyone who thinks this is a really stupid question.

```
int main()
{
      char hexalpha[] = "aAbBcCdDeEfF";
      int i, c;
      int answer = 0;

      c = getchar();

      for (i= 0; answer == 0 && hexalpha[i] != "\0"; ++i)
      {
           if(hexalpha[i]== c)
               answer = (10 + (i/2));
      }

    return answer;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't correctly read what you enter ?

Comment: What are you entering and what happens when you enter it? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: If your problem is that you don't _see_ the result, try printing instead of returning it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare strings with `!=` , and `hexalpha[i]` is a `char`. So you'd want `hexalpha[i] != '\0'` instead of `hexalpha[i] != "\0"`

Returning the answer from main() is a bit clumsy, printing out the answer would be easier, so do

```
printf("Answer: %d\n", answer);
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `answer`, not printing it. Your problem isn't input, it's output. Return passes the value to whatever function called it (or gives an exit status in the case of `main`).
At the beginning of your code, add the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

At the end of `main`, replace `return answer;` with:

```
    printf("%i\n", answer);
    return 0;
```

Also, I'd recommend replacing `"0"` with `'0'` in the for loop. Your compiler will give you a warning because it should be a `char`, not a `*char`.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem anything wrong with your use of `getchar`. There is however a problem with the second half of your loop-condition: you compare an `int` (`c`) with a string (`"\0"`). You probably mean to use `hexalpha[i] != '\0'` (note the single-quotes).

Besides that, you don't see the answer because it's never printed. In most shells you can print the return-value of the last program with `$?` (on Windows it's `%errorlevel%`), like this:

```
echo $?
```

For example, if I run the program like this:

```
> a.out
b
> echo $?
11
```

You see that `getchar` works correctly, but you don't see the output because the shell doesn't usually print the return-value of a program. Alternatively, you can add a `printf`-statement at the end of your program. This is recommended anyway because the return-value of main is more commonly used to determine whether the program finished successfully, or not.

```
    printf("%i\n", answer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The OP didn't mention what platform he's on, but on Windows you need `echo %errorlevel%` rather than `echo $?`. I'd say the thing to do is print the answer _and_ return it. Doesn't cost anything to do so, after all.